# why call back Function can not pass test jest in react ? callBack function is not a function(testing Checkbox.Group in React with jest)

Tags: reactjs, ts-jest

this is my test

```html
describe('MultipleDaySelector', () => {
  test('checked the MultipleDaySelector', () => {
    const propVal = ''
    const { container } = render(<MultipleDaySelector parentCallbackMultipleDaySelector={propVal} />)
    const checkBoxes = container.querySelector('[type="checkbox"]') as HTMLElement
    expect(checkBoxes).not.toBe(null);
    act(() => {
      userEvent.click(checkBoxes)
    });
    expect(checkBoxes).toBeChecked()
  })
})
```

Here is my function

```html
export default function MultipleDaySelector({ parentCallbackMultipleDaySelector }): JSX.Element {
  const onChange = (value) => parentCallbackMultipleDaySelector(value)

  return <>
    <Checkbox.Group
      data-testid="MultipleDaySelectorTest"
      onChange={onChange}
      name="MultipleDaySelector"
      options={[
        { label: "Monday", value: "1" },
        { label: "Tuesday", value: "2" },
        { label: "Wednesday", value: "3" },
        { label: "Thursday", value: "4" },
        { label: "Friday", value: "5" },
        { label: "Saturday", value: "6" },
        { label: "Sunday", value: "0" }
      ]}
    />
  </>
}
```

As you can see I am going to test MultipleDaySelector function , when I run the test I will get error

```html
TypeError: parentCallbackMultipleDaySelector is not a function

      3 | 
      4 | export default function MultipleDaySelector({ parentCallbackMultipleDaySelector }): JSX.Element {
    > 5 |   const onChange = (value: any) => parentCallbackMultipleDaySelector(value)
        |                                    ^
      6 | 
      7 |   return <>
      8 |     <Checkbox.Group
```

when I delete parentCallbackMultipleDaySelector test is working fine, but I have no idea about what is a problem with a callback function

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:** You are passing a string, not a function, as a prop in the test

```
describe('MultipleDaySelector', () => {
  test('checked the MultipleDaySelector', () => {

    const propVal = '' // <-- This is a string!!

    const { container } = render(<MultipleDaySelector parentCallbackMultipleDaySelector={propVal} />)
    const checkBoxes = container.querySelector('[type="checkbox"]') as HTMLElement
    expect(checkBoxes).not.toBe(null);
    act(() => {
      userEvent.click(checkBoxes)
    });
    expect(checkBoxes).toBeChecked()
  })
})
```

This line in the function forces prop `parentCallbackMultipleDaySelector` to need to be a function:

```
const onChange = (value) => parentCallbackMultipleDaySelector(value)
```

**Solution:** Pass a function, i.e. `() => {}` or `jest.fn()`

```
describe('MultipleDaySelector', () => {
  test('checked the MultipleDaySelector', () => {

    const propVal = jest.fn();

    const { container } = render(<MultipleDaySelector parentCallbackMultipleDaySelector={propVal} />)
    const checkBoxes = container.querySelector('[type="checkbox"]') as HTMLElement
    expect(checkBoxes).not.toBe(null);
    act(() => {
      userEvent.click(checkBoxes)
    });
    expect(checkBoxes).toBeChecked()
  })
})
```